# TestCafe works with SAM Local but not after SAM Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda, puppeteer, testcafe

I'm currently trying to set up an AWS Lambda (nodejs10.x) function that should execute a simple TestCafe test.

If I run my Lambda locally with `sam local invoke --no-event` it executes just fine:

> 2019-12-03T13:39:46.345Z        7b906b79-d7e5-1aa6-edb7-3e749d4e4b08
>   INFO    hello world  ✓ My first test  1 passed (1s)
>   2019-12-03T13:39:46.578Z        7b906b79-d7e5-1aa6-edb7-3e749d4e4b08
>   INFO    Tests failed: 0

After I deployed it with `sam build` and `sam deploy` it stops working. It just throws the following error in AWS:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Page crashed!",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Page crashed!",
    "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:203:15)",
    "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
    "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
  ]
}
```

My lambda handler looks like this:

```
const createTestCafe = require("testcafe");
const chromium = require("chrome-aws-lambda");
let testcafe = null;

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  const executablePath = await chromium.executablePath;

  await createTestCafe()
    .then(tc => {
      testcafe = tc;
      const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

      return runner
        .src("sample-fixture.js")
        .browsers(
          "puppeteer-core:launch?arg=--no-sandbox&arg=--disable-gpu&arg=--disable-setuid-sandbox&path=" + executablePath
        )
        .run({
          skipJsErrors: true,
          selectorTimeout: 50000
        });
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
      console.log("Tests failed: " + failedCount);
      testcafe.close();
    });

  return {
    statusCode: 200
  };
};
```

My sample-fixture.js looks like this:

```
fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
  console.log('hello world');
});
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

- "testcafe": "^1.7.0"
- "chrome-aws-lambda": "^2.0.1"
- "testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer-core": "^1.1.0"

Has someone an idea why my Lambda functions works locally on my machine but not in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot currently say anything precise based only on this information.
I suggest you try the following:

- Check that packet deployed size is less then 50 Mb (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-lambda)
- Check that testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer-core  can be run on the AWS Labmda

Answer (score 0):

So I've been able to run testcafe in an AWS lambda. The key for me was to take advantage of Lambda Layers. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

The issue with testcafe it that it's a huge package, both it and chrome-aws-lambda should be deployed in Layers, as you may exceed the bundle size limit.

Also, you may run into an issue with speed on the Lambda as testcafe compiles the files in babel. If your files are already compiled it may add additional unneeded time to your execution.

Hope this helps!